# How to add a plot with no y value

Tags: ios, core-plot

I already have an chart like this [Chart 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvQmA.png)

The day 9/28 and 9/30 plot are displayed continuously. I want to display 9/29 plot with no data, and expect the red line go from 9/28 to 9/30.

So I add 9/29 plot, with x = 9/29 and return value nil for 9/29 in this fuction

```
- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                  field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
            recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

But no line shows up, like this: [Chart 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG3D8.png)

Is there any way to achieve the chart I want? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't return values for the dates you want to skip. For the second chart, it only shows three data points (9/28, 9/30, and 10/3). Return three (3) from `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` and only return data values for those dates.

Comment: How to do it? `- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                      field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
                recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` requires a NSNumber for return, right? even with if else, at the end you have to provide a default value.

Comment: Return the values for 9/28 at index 0, 9/30 at index 1, and 10/3 at index 2.

Comment: But I want to display the 9/29 day.so that the distance from (9/28 to 9/30) !=(9/30 to 10/3)  Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: The plot data is independent of the axis labels. The x-axis is already set up the way you want it. Don't change it.